# Using programmatically created UIButtons with the same method to load different UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have programmatically generated UIButtons that all share the same selector method.  When the method runs I would like the method to know which button was pressed and then be able to load a corresponding UIViewController.

```
-(void)buildButtons
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [aButton setTag:i];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aView addSubview:aButton];
}
```

Then:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"Button %ld clicked.", (long int)[button tag]);
    // code here that picks the correct viewController to push to...
    // for example tag 1 would create an instance of vcTwo.m and would then be pushed to the navigationController and be displayed on screen
}
```

say I have three UIViewController classes (vcOne.m, vcTwo.m, vcThree.m) and I want it so that when the button is pressed 'buttonClicked' is run and the code picks the corresponding viewController to push to.  I don't want to use a series of if statements as there may be dozens/hundreds of viewControllers in the end.  Would I have to instantiate all of the viewControllers and put them in an array?  Is there a better way?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947561/uibuttons-image-scrolling-with-scrollview-but-its-action-method-remains-on-orig/23948036#23948036

Comment: Every button has a `tag` property. You can use it to distinguish which button was pressed. :)

Comment: @karthikeyan - These has to be a better way?  Or am I missing something?  What if there were 100 viewControllers?  I would need a 100 case long switch statement and then 100 hardcoded methods.  Doesn't seem very OO.

Comment: @AbhishekBedi - You will see in my question that I am already capturing the values of the button's tag property and working from there ;)

Comment: you have to instantiate all the viewControllers and put them in array- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"Button %ld clicked.", (long int)[button tag]);
    NSInteger tag=[button tag];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[commonArray objectAtIndex:tag] animated:YES];
    
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with this:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button tag = %li", (long)[sender tag]);
    FormularyVC *formularyVCInstance = [FormularyVC alloc];
    ProceduresVC *proceduresVCInstance = [ProceduresVC alloc];
    VetMedVC *vetMedVCInstance = [VetMedVC alloc];

    NSArray *vcArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:formularyVCInstance, proceduresVCInstance, vetMedVCInstance, nil];

    UIViewController *vcToLoad = [vcArray objectAtIndex:(int)[sender tag]];
    vcToLoad.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcToLoad animated:NO];

}
```

I created an array of the ViewControllers I wanted to be able to load based on which button was pressed.  When the button is pressed the method is run and the tag is taken as a parameter.  This tag is used to find the ViewController needed by checking its location on the array's index.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using storyboards? so you can chose a segue according to the button tag:

```
int i = (int)[button tag];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segue%d", i] sender:self];
```

or:

```
UIViewController *viewController= [controller.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSString stringWithFormat:@"ViewControllerNumber%d", i];
```

Comment: I am not using storyboards but would like something similar to your second suggestion along the lines of: [self.navigationController pushViewController:[vcArray objectAtIndex:i] animated:NO];

Comment: I suggest you to not alloc and init all your Controllers before knowing what buttons was pressed. You will waste memory for free. Put a suggestive name to the nib so you can link them with the button tags. Try something like that: UIViewController *aViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ViewControllerNumber%d", buttonTag] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Comment: Or, if you want, you can store in a `NSArray` all your nib names and then alloc and init the corresponding NibName for that button. But it's a lot of work to manually put each nib name in the array.

Comment: That sounds promising.  As mentioned earlier, I'm not using storyboards, I have the class files for the UIViewController classes that I need to link to at the moment, can I still use nib names?

Comment: The code i used in my first comment it's the way you can init a UIViewController when using xib (not storyboards). `YourViewController *controller = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourCustomNibName" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`

Comment: This is the way you set the nib name: http://i.stack.imgur.com/onqXD.png
You have to select the xib file, select the whole window and this menu will show in the left pane. Hope you will figure out!