# Adding Array of UIButtons in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I would like to add `UIButton` using for loop. Each button would have a different action.
My code is:

```
NSArray *methods = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", @"3", @"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15", nil];
int x=0;
for (int t=0;t<=14;t++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector([methods[t]]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(275, x+8, 28, 16);
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 10.0/255.0f green:100.0/255.0f blue:150.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [segmentedView1 addSubview:button];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedView1];
    x+=20;
}
```

Stuck with an error: 
`"Expected identifier" in the line  [button addTarget:self action:@selector([methods[t]])`

Also,how do i make outlets for such buttons added programatically?

Any solution?
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112643/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-selector-at-runtime-with-objective-c Looks like your answer but using tag is better than this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIButton's image scrolling with scrollview but its action/method remains on original position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947561/uibuttons-image-scrolling-with-scrollview-but-its-action-method-remains-on-orig)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947561/uibuttons-image-scrolling-with-scrollview-but-its-action-method-remains-on-orig/23948036#23948036

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to assign same selector for all the buttons. Pointer to the button will be send to this selector and you can recognize which button was pressed using `.tag` property for example.

```
for (int t=0;t<=14;t++) {
   ...
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   button.tag = i;
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
   if (((UIButton *)sender).tag == 1) {
      ... 
   }
   ...
}
```

Also move `[self.view addSubview:segmentedView1];` outside of your loop.

Comment: can u please elaborate using this .tag property?

Comment: Got it..thanks..But a small correction here.."buttonPressed:" ..double quotes are not required.Cheers

Comment: Or even without any quotes.

Comment: Can u please tell me how do i make oultets for these kind of buttons added programatically?

Comment: Why do you need outlets for them? Outlets are to bind elements from the storyboard to properties.

Comment: actually..i have a button to expand(+) a view and beneath it a button to compress(-) the view. So,when i press (+) button ,it should get disappeared and the (-) button should come up..how do i do that in this case..like i have an array of (+) buttons and (-) buttons?

Comment: Just create a property with NSArray and put all buttons there.

Comment: like? Can u tell me how to do it for the above created buttons?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *selectorName = methods[t];
SEL method = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);

[button addTarget:self action:method forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

don't forget, you have to implement all these selectors and if you keep methods in array it's potentially pretty risky. I would suggest to use one action for all buttons and handle it via `tag` property inside your action.

If not, try to wrap:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:method]) {
    [button addTarget:self action:method forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: This is not the right way to implement many control behaving in similar way. You should combine all handlers into one.

Comment: you should have added this comment to original question, I've just answered on it, how to avoid such error

Comment: This is actually quite wrong I think. If you see that OP is going wrong direction with his approach - you should inform him about it, and not answering exact question and letting him go even further.

Comment: agree >> if you keep methods in array it's potentially pretty risky.

Comment: Can u please tell me how do i make oultets for these kind of buttons added programatically?

Answer (score 0):

#### @selector expects a method, not an object

you have to do like

```
- (void)onClick:(UIBUtton*)sender {
    if(sender.tag == 1) {
        // ....
    }
}

button.tag = i;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick)
```

Comment: Yes..but each button would have a different action in  my case..How to make this possible>

Comment: You have to switch your button inside the handler. I updated my answer.

Comment: Can u please tell me how do i make oultets for these kind of buttons added programatically?

Comment: There is no need for outlets since they are to connect interfacebuilder to code. Since your buttons are genereated in code, you already have full access to them.